# CCSprite not appearing in CCLayerColor

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

i have a ccsprite which i would like to place inside a CCLayerColor but for some reason its not showing up inside of it. i have the following code and i'm stumped why it isn't showing up.

```
[self setColor:ccGREEN];
  [self setOpacity:255];
  [self setPosition:(CGPointMake(0, 60/2+bottomPadding))];
  self.inventoryHolder = [[CCSprite alloc] init];
  [self.inventoryHolder setTextureRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 60)];
  [self.inventoryHolder setColor:ccc3(255, 0, 0)];
  self.inventoryHolder.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0);
  self.inventoryHolder.position = ccp(0, 60/2+50);
  [self addChild:self.inventoryHolder z:100];
```

self being the CCLayerColor and self.inventoryHolder being the CCSprite. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973909/white-color-overlay-on-ccsprite

Comment: i've just replaced the sprite with a layercolor instead and it still does not display.

Comment: Are you at least seeing the green color that you've set?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't actually set a texture in the sprite, so there's nothing for it to display.